# Scala loop over 2 sequences at the same time

Tags: scala

I have these 2 Scala sequences, I need to check whether they are equal or not, ***ignoring nullable column***.

```
val schemaA = StructType(Seq(StructField("date",DateType,true), StructField("account_name",StringType,true)))

val df_A = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], schemaA)

val schemaB = StructType(Seq(StructField("date",DateType,false), StructField("account_name",StringType,true)))

val df_B = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], schemaB)
```

In python, I could have simply done this:

```
 print(
     all(        
         for a,b in zip(df_A.schema, df_B.schema)
           (a.name, a.dataType) == (b.name, b.dataType)
     )
 )
```

But I got stuck to do the same thing in `Scala`, any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to go around the "extra columns" problem mentioned in the comments:

```
val result = schemaA.map { a => a.name -> a.type } == schemaB.map { b => b.name -> b.type }
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite similarly to your Python solution:

```
val result: Boolean = schemaA.zip(schemaB).forall {
  case (a, b) => (a.name, a.dataType) == (b.name, b.dataType)
}
```

(no need to use the DFs).

Do note that both this solution and the python one might return `true` when one of the schemas has extra fields that the otherone doesn't, because `zip` would simply ignore them.

Comment: hmmm, actually I do care if there is an extra column or not, how can I fix that? I need to check both schemas are exactly equal. maybe by adding an extra check for the length?

Comment: Adding extra length check would be a valid solution, yes